# On sheaf quotient

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Let $X$ be a scheme and $G$ be a group acting on $X$. Suppose the action is not free. Consider the quotient sheaf $X/G.$ Can we directly prove that the sheaf quotient is not an algebraic space?

Comment: The sheaf quotient is a sheaf of sets, and in some cases may be represented by an algebraic space.  The stack quotient is a stack.

Comment: @S. Carnahan Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Say the action is free if $G \times X \to X \times X$, $(g, x) \mapsto (g\cdot x, x)$ is a monomorphism.  (Convince yourself this is the right definition.)

This condition is actually *equivalent* to the quotient stack $[X/G]$ being an algebraic space. Indeed recall an algebraic stack is an algebraic space iff its diagonal is a monomorphism (meaning that it is a sheaf of *sets*). Now that condition can be checked smooth-locally on the target, and if you pull back the diagonal along $X \times X \to [X/G] \times [X/G]$ (square of the quotient map), you get precisely the map $G\times X \to X\times X$ above.